# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Vue-Picture-BD-Marker'

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, vuejs2, module

My vue project works well on my own macbook and can npm build successfully.But when I'm trying to deploy it on my centos server using jenkins, it build failed.The whole log is

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/Mark.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Vue-Picture-BD-Marker' in '/app/src/views'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/Mark.vue 50:0-49
 @ ./src/views/Mark.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js[39m[22m

  Build failed with errors.
```

Can anyone help me?I'm confused.Thank you very much

It builds successfully on my server when I dont import vue-picture-bd-marker.But this module works well on my local environment.

The whole jenkins log is like below

````
```Step 1/12 : FROM node:10 as build-stage
 ---> 28dca6642db8
Step 2/12 : LABEL maintainer="finn"
 ---> Running in 3a4f55bf5c90
Removing intermediate container 3a4f55bf5c90
 ---> 1f69f1d2a72d
Step 3/12 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 9b3d5d53dbbf
Removing intermediate container 9b3d5d53dbbf
 ---> 76b3e9a47276
Step 4/12 : COPY . .
 ---> 67ecea023b88
Step 5/12 : RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org/
 ---> Running in 5ee2b9a7017d
Removing intermediate container 5ee2b9a7017d
 ---> 7612b0801936
Step 6/12 : RUN npm install vue-picture-bd-marker -S
 ---> Running in 525463f9c177

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

[96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

[96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
[96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
[96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m

[96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /app/node_modules/ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing [35mEJS[0m: built with the [32mJake[0m JavaScript build tool ([32mhttps://jakejs.com/[0m)


> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /app/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> core-js@3.26.0 postinstall /app/node_modules/vue-picture-bd-marker/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

[96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

[96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js:[0m
[96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
[96m>[94m https://patreon.com/zloirock [0m
[96m>[94m bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz [0m

[96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m

[91mnpm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0 requires a peer of eslint@^6.2.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-eslint-parser@7.11.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[0m[91mnpm WARN acorn-jsx@5.3.2 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
[0m[91mnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

[0m+ vue-picture-bd-marker@1.4.6
added 1357 packages from 718 contributors in 25.494s

80 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Removing intermediate container 525463f9c177
 ---> f38029d78fba
Step 7/12 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in ce44e7ed2964
[91mnpm WARN acorn-jsx@5.3.2 requires a peer of acorn@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@7.20.0 requires a peer of eslint@^6.2.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[0m[91mnpm WARN style-loader@3.3.1 requires a peer of webpack@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN stylus-loader@7.1.0 requires a peer of stylus@>=0.52.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN stylus-loader@7.1.0 requires a peer of webpack@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN update-browserslist-db@1.0.10 requires a peer of browserslist@>= 4.21.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[0m[91mnpm WARN vue-eslint-parser@7.11.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
[0m[91mnpm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

[0mup to date in 5.824s

80 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Removing intermediate container ce44e7ed2964
 ---> 9cc90e464d52
Step 8/12 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 2c230d59bfcd

> drtool-vue@1.0.0 build /app
> node build/build.js

Hash: [1m403f85fa3eac2561beea[39m[22m
Version: webpack [1m3.12.0[39m[22m
Time: [1m27286[39m[22mms
                                                  [1mAsset[39m[22m       [1mSize[39m[22m  [1mChunks[39m[22m  [1m[39m[22m           [1m[39m[22m       [1mChunk Names[39m[22m
    [1m[32mstatic/css/app.973c70332ba0b7777e4e169660c4c590.css[39m[22m     241 kB       [1m1[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         app
                [1m[32mstatic/fonts/element-icons.535877f.woff[39m[22m    28.2 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
               [1m[33mstatic/js/vendor.30f6ae5de4596c007430.js[39m[22m    [1m[33m1.13 MB[39m[22m       [1m0[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m  [1m[33m[big][39m[22m  vendor
                  [1m[32mstatic/js/app.07da158772daae0903c6.js[39m[22m    1.75 kB       [1m1[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         app
             [1m[32mstatic/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js[39m[22m  857 bytes       [1m2[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         manifest
                 [1m[32mstatic/fonts/element-icons.732389d.ttf[39m[22m      56 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
[1m[32mstatic/css/app.973c70332ba0b7777e4e169660c4c590.css.map[39m[22m     342 kB        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         
           [1m[32mstatic/js/vendor.30f6ae5de4596c007430.js.map[39m[22m    4.38 MB       [1m0[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         vendor
              [1m[32mstatic/js/app.07da158772daae0903c6.js.map[39m[22m    10.2 kB       [1m1[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         app
         [1m[32mstatic/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map[39m[22m    4.97 kB       [1m2[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         manifest
                                             [1m[32mindex.html[39m[22m  512 bytes        [1m[39m[22m  [1m[32m[emitted][39m[22m         

[1m[31mERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/Mark.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'Vue-Picture-BD-Marker' in '/app/src/views'
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/Mark.vue 50:0-49
 @ ./src/views/Mark.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js[39m[22m

  Build failed with errors.

[91mnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
[0m[91mnpm ERR! drtool-vue@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the drtool-vue@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0m[91m
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-02T03_52_20_178Z-debug.log
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' returned a non-zero code: 1
d482ed42ced2
c5d0729d1568fec712980310990231e89792457807078e48bc6a9c265ca95c71
Finished: SUCCESS
````

Comment: I have ran npm install before build on my server

Comment: Hard to help without the actual code. Especially the part missing from the error + the deploy settings.

Comment: thanks for comment! I import this module like this: import {AIMarker} from "Vue-Picture-BD-Marker"; and it works well in local environment.There is nearly no deploy settings, just run shell by jenkins.npm install and npm run build.

Comment: [That package](https://github.com/sunshengfei/vue-vmarker) so? I'm not sure that it's a good idea to use that one overall, since there is no accessible documentation, for me at least. And it's in damn chinese, so getting any issue solved would be an issue. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: you got the point...Its document website was not down when I started this project and import this package.I'm trying to develop a tool to mark images for machine learning and this package will help.I'm new with frontend so it's a little hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by replacing `import {AIMarker} from "Vue-Picture-BD-Marker"` with `import {AIMarker} from "vue-picture-bd-marker"` Note that macos or windows is not sensitive with upper and lower case, but linux is.